# Azure Pipelines - Is there a way to view the folder structure?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm struggling to picture the folder structure of azure pipelines. I know there are some implicit directories like:

- $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
- $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

Which are both folders on a specific build agent available from the pool.

Is there a way to view the folder structure and get a better understanding how things are laid out?

Comment: The documentation gives examples of the folder structure.

Comment: See [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [classic release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch). The `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` has different values in release pipeline.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use [CMD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to call [tree command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree) in Microsoft-Hosted windows agent to get the folder structure.

**My script:**

```
echo "Structure of work folder of this pipeline:"
tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)\1 /f

echo "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory:" 

echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"

echo "Build.BinariesDirectory:" 

echo "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"

echo "Build.SourcesDirectory:"

echo "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
```

**The result:**

[image]

`$(Agent.WorkFolder)` represents the working folder for current agent, `$(Agent.WorkFolder)\1` represents the working folder for current pipeline.(Normally the first pipeline will be put in `$(Agent.WorkFolder)\1`, and the second `$(Agent.WorkFolder)\2`...)

So it's obvious that for one pipeline run, it has four folders by default: a(artifact folder), b(binaries folder), s(source folder) and TestResults(Test results folder). The `s` folder is where the source code files are downloaded. For build pipeline: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`,`$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)` and `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` represent the same folder. More details see [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: This REALLY helped me figure out a pathing issue I had.  Thank you!!!!!

Comment: This answer was very helpful but for my RELEASE pipeline, I found that my folder tree was D:\A\r1 rather than D:\A\1. So I used the command "tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)\r1 /f"

Comment: Will this work if the agent is linux based?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Without this answer I would not have been able to manage the issues with our build pipe!

Comment: Make sure to run `tree -a $(Agent.WorkFolder)\1 /f` in case you want to show hidden items. 
In my case I was interested in the .pipelines folder.

Answer (score 23):

Another option is to add this to a YAML pipeline:

```
- powershell: Get-ChildItem -Path 'Insert root path' -recurse
```

It will look something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\*.txt -Recurse -Force

Directory: C:\Test\Logs\Adirectory

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/12/2019     16:16             20 Afile4.txt
-a-h--        2/12/2019     15:52             22 hiddenfile.txt
-a----        2/13/2019     13:26             20 LogFile4.txt

    Directory: C:\Test\Logs\Backup

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/12/2019     16:16             20 ATextFile.txt
-a----        2/12/2019     15:50             20 LogFile3.txt

    Directory: C:\Test\Logs

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/12/2019     16:16             20 Afile.txt
-a-h--        2/12/2019     15:52             22 hiddenfile.txt
-a----        2/13/2019     13:26             20 LogFile1.txt

    Directory: C:\Test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/13/2019     08:55             26 anotherfile.txt
-a----        2/12/2019     15:40         118014 Command.txt
-a-h--        2/12/2019     15:52             22 hiddenfile.txt
-ar---        2/12/2019     14:31             27 ReadOnlyFile.txt
```

Here is [documentation on the Get-ChildItem command if you need more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321)

Comment: in my yaml I wanted to use the powershell@2 task (this is not formatted for yaml but you get the idea):

`- task: PowerShell@2  
   inputs:  
   targetType: inline  
   script: Get-ChildItem -Path '$(Agent.WorkFolder)\*.*' -recurse -force`

Comment: This will not write the file name on linux agents

Comment: This is the way

Comment: @noontz did you find a workaround? There seems to be an issue with unix and the console width -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728509/azure-devops-powershell-not-showing-file-names-for-get-childitem

Comment: @Tommy  Scroll a little down ;)   I added a link in a comment on your provided link e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74316936/2050637

Comment: As you are not sure what the current working directory is, it's worth using this as `Get-ChildItem -recurse` with no path specified.

Answer (score 21):

@LoLance's answer is perfect for Windows agents.  For Linux agents, the syntax is slightly different (reverse the slash, and remove the /f flag):

```yaml
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "Structure of work folder of this pipeline:"
          tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)/1

          echo "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory:" 
          echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"

          echo "Build.BinariesDirectory:" 
          echo "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"

          echo "Build.SourcesDirectory:"
          echo "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
```

Comment: thx for the linux variation..  I was using powershell Get-ChildItem, but for some reason "my" linux agent does not print the filename..

Answer (score 14):

[image]

source: [user comment from this blog](https://dev.to/shleeen/understanding-the-directory-structure-created-by-azure-devops-tasks-1328)

Note that your full path may look different based on your environment.

For example: your Build.StagingDirectory path could be **c:\agent_work\1\a**
OR
**/home/vsts/work/1/a/**

This is based on Agent.BuildDirectory or Pipeline.Workspace variable.(c:\agent_work\1 or /home/vsts/work/1 or /a/1 or something similar)

[more in azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation gives you examples of the folder structure. If that's not enough, add a PowerShell step that runs `gci -rec -directory | select-object fullname` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

It looks more like this(work directory of an Agent):

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to obtain this view without running self-hosted agents?

Comment: Write a Powershell script to get and print all folders

Comment: Review to the answer provided on running an inline Powershell task. This should work irregardless of where the agent is hosted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was working in DevOps pipeline for AKS application deployment. I was not able to find the exact path of my deployment.yml and service.yml

My azure-pipeline.yml code is the following

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  imageRepo: inboundapi
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build an image
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'msdacrconnect'
        repository: '$(imageRepo)'
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
          latest
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/manifests'
        artifact: 'manifests'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy image
  dependsOn: Build
  variables:
    acrsecret: aksacrsecret
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy to AKS
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            artifactName: 'manifests'
            targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests'
        - task: KubernetesManifest@0
          inputs:
            action: 'createSecret'
            kubernetesServiceConnection: 'aksclustersvccon'
            namespace: 'inboundapiapp'
            secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
            secretName: '$(acrsecret)'
            dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'msdacrconnect'      
        - task: KubernetesManifest@0
          inputs:
            action: 'deploy'
            kubernetesServiceConnection: 'aksclustersvccon'
            namespace: 'default'
            manifests: |
              $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/deployment.yml
              $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/service.yml
```

It was showing me the following error

```
##[error]No manifest file(s) matching /home/vsts/work/1/s/'/home/vsts/work/1/deployment.yml','/home/vsts/work/1/service.yml' was found.
```

suddenly I got this post and checked with the following yml. It's work and I found my artifact path.

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  imageRepo: inboundapi
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy image
  variables:
    acrsecret: aksacrsecret
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy to AKS
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:        
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
              echo "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
              tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```