# Python Package publish in Azure DevOps Artifacts: 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

A. Used `twine` to authenticate and publish my Python packages to an Azure Artifacts feed

```
     - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: Build Artifacts
        inputs:
          script:
            echo Building distribution package
            python -m pip install --upgrade twine build setuptools
            python -m build 
      
      - task: TwineAuthenticate@1
        inputs:
          artifactFeed: ddey-feed
      - script:
          python -m twine upload -r "ddey-feed" --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*.whl
```

B. Although it ran successfully, but I didn't get any package in Artifacts. I found the `Warning:'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact`

C. I did some research and  decided to add additional section which does a `copy and publish`

```
          - task: CopyFiles@2
           displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
           inputs:
            SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            Contents: |
              **/*
              !.git/**/*
            TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
           condition: succeededOrFailed()
    
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
            inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

`Can anyone please comment what else I can modify in yaml file to get the package available in Artifacts?`

**Different Tried things after Suggestions:**

1. Add [Tree command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree) to see all build folders to confirm generation of file:

[image]

**2. After removing `source folder` and let it use default source**
[image]

successful build and consumed:
[image]

Artifacts is generated and I can see it from pipeline.
[image]

**Problem Statement**

In Artifacts tab, I don't see the build available in any feed. How to connect the build with a specific feed (ddey-feed). I though `TwineAuthenticate` is suppose to take care of it.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if in your $(Build.SourcesDirectory) contains any files and then after copy if any files are in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)? Here you have how to check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117797/azure-pipelines-is-there-a-way-to-view-the-folder-structure

Comment: Great idea! I tried and finding the files are in the folder.

Answer (score 3):

ok. I have finally resolved the whole issue and could deploy the package to Artifacts Feed.

Key learning:

- When creating Artifacts Feed, Make sure to check permission. Add `Allow project-scoped builds` otherwise will get [permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68461699/twine-upload-to-artifacts-feed-failing) in pushing package from Azure pipeline
- You need to define `PYPIRC_PATH` to point where .pypirc file reside. This can be done using environment variable set-up as shown below

> ```
> - script: |
>    echo "$(PYPIRC_PATH)"
>    
>    python -m twine upload -r ddey-feed --verbose --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/*
>   displayName: 'cmd to push package to Artifact Feed'
>   env:
>     PYPIRC_PATH: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
> ```

- Make sure `Twine Authenticate` feed name matches with `twine upload` feed name. If pipeline fails to push the package, you can try to run following command directly from your repo: `twine upload -r ddey-feed --config-file ./.pypirc dist/` and it should successfully upload the build to Artifacts.
- For debug purpose, print the directories.

  ```
  echo "Structure of work folder of this pipeline:"

  tree $(Agent.WorkFolder)\1 /f

  echo "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory:" 

  echo "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"

  echo "Build.BinariesDirectory:" 

  echo "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"

  echo "Build.SourcesDirectory:"

  echo "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
  ```
- Summary of components of the pipeline

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indentation before CopyFiles@2
[image]

Comment: that is probably why CopyFiles does not copy files to D:/A/1/A according to your screenshot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: And indentation in PublishBuildArtifacts after inputs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: Actually yml was so long I had to chop it to paste in stackoverflow. Indentation was due to copy-paste issue. That error is gone now after I remove `SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'` in `CopyFiles2` and let it pick default. I'm getting my build. But I still can't see it in Artifacts (expected to see the build there)

Comment: I have done example repo with working example can you take a look if everything is similar to yours?

https://dev.azure.com/tomaszkontek/FeaturesTesting/_git/TestCopyFiles?path=%2Fazure-pipelines.yml
|
https://dev.azure.com/tomaszkontek/FeaturesTesting/_build/results?buildId=72&view=results

https://dev.azure.com/tomaszkontek/FeaturesTesting/_build/results?buildId=72&view=artifacts&pathAsName=false&type=publishedArtifacts

Comment: Nice.  I see your also showing `published` which is same state as mine. But when I visit the `Artifacts` tab, I was expecting to see that published package there. Is it wrong expectation?

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood the case, PublishBuildArtifacts@1 can not publish artifacts to the Artifacts Feed

Comment: Then Twine needs to upload your artifacts, are you sure that is should contain dist/*.whl
 parameter and not something like "build"?

Comment: Artifacts published by PublishBuildArtifacts@1 are used for CI/CD, and used then in another stages/releases/pipelines

Meanwhile artifacts published to Artifacts feed can be used for example as Nuget/Python/Maven packages to be downloaded from there.