# Twine upload to Artifacts Feed failing

Tags: python, azure, devops, artifact, twine

1. I have a python package *build successfully* and trying Publish Python packages to Azure Artifacts feeds. My package directory structure is following:

> ```
> my_pkg
>   my_pkg
>     start.py
>  tests
>     test_start.py
> .pypirc
> ```

2. .pypirc looks like this:

   ```
    [distutils]
    Index-servers =
     ddey-feed

    [ddey-feed]
    Repository = https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/project
   ```
3. Below is my pipeline:

[image]

4. yaml set-up for Command Line script for Artifact Feed is following:

steps:

```
- script: |
   pip install twine keyring artifacts-keyring
   
   echo "$(PYPIRC_PATH)"
   
   python -m twine upload -r ddey-feed --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) build/*
  displayName: 'Command Line Script for Artifact Feed'
  env:
    PYPIRC_PATH: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

*Problem Statement:*
Although I set-up the variable `PYPIRC_PATH` to point to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, when I printed it is showing following `"D:\a\_temp\twineAuthenticate\MXAJzL\.pypirc"`. It leads to the following below error to execute this command.

**HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/**

Any suggestion how to set-up PYPIRC_PATH in yaml for windows?

Answer (score 1):

Build Scope permission issue was propagating from the fact that the project build was being feed from Azure pipeline(`Build Artifacts`) and it requires different level of permission for the Azure Feed - [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines)

*To use packages from a feed in Azure Pipelines, the appropriate build identity must have permission to your feed. By default, the Project Collection Build Service is a Contributor. If you've changed your builds to run at project scope, you'll need to add the project-level build identity as a Reader or Contributor, as desired.*

[image]