# No test result files matching D:\build\V1\_w\1\s\test\target\reports\*.xml were found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have configured azure pipeline for running my build.
While running test case step the build ran with status “success” with message: No test result files matching D:\build\V1_w\1\s\test\target\reports*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped”

And after this when zip file is creating automatically as part of build “create zip with failed tests info” it failed the build with error message: ##[error] Error: Achieve creation failed for archive file: D:\build\V1_w\1\s\tests\target\reports.zip ENOENT

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I have done all the required right configuration but still it’s occurring.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the Pipeline?

Comment: @subhankars - I need at least 10 reputation to post an screenshot as per stack overflow policy.

Comment: Could you share output from your tasks and their definitions? If you are using hosted agents then check what files and where are on agent using command from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117797/azure-pipelines-is-there-a-way-to-view-the-folder-structure

Comment: @Kontekst - Task: create zip with failed test:                                                                  
 Error: ##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory , stat 'D:\build\V1\_w\1\s\tests\target\reports\*.xml' Found 0 files.