# Terrafrom Init is failing to locate module when providing relative path

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, yaml, terraform, cicd

I've started building an infrastructure using terraform. Within that TF configuration I am calling a module to be used by using relative path. This is successful in a classic release but I have been tasked with converting the pipeline to yaml. When I run terraform init step the agent finds the Tf config files but can't find the modules folder even though the artifact was downloaded on a previous task.

yaml file:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Dashboard-infra
    project: Infrastructure
    source: IT Dashboard
  - pipeline: Infra-modules
    project: Infrastructure
    source: AWS Modules
    trigger: true

stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Test
  variables:
  - group: "Non-Prod Keys"
  jobs:
    - deployment:
      displayName: string
      variables:
       region: us-east-1
       app_name: it-dashboard
       environment: test
       tf.path: 'IT Dashboard'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      environment: test
      strategy:
        runOnce:
         deploy:
            steps:
            - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'specific'
                project: '23e9505e-a627-4681-9598-2bd8b6c1204c'
                pipeline: '547'
                buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
                downloadType: 'single'
                artifactName: 'drop'
                downloadPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s'

            - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
              inputs:
                buildType: 'specific'
                project: '23e9505e-a627-4681-9598-2bd8b6c1204c'
                pipeline: '88'
                buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
                downloadType: 'single'
                artifactName: 'Modules'
                downloadPath: '$(agent.builddirectory)/s'
            - task: ExtractFiles@1
              inputs:
                archiveFilePatterns: 'drop/infrastructure.zip'
                destinationFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
                cleanDestinationFolder: false
                overwriteExistingFiles: false
                
            - task: ExtractFiles@1
              inputs:
                archiveFilePatterns: 'Modules/drop.zip'
                destinationFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
                cleanDestinationFolder: false
                overwriteExistingFiles: false
            - task: TerraformInstaller@0
              inputs:
                terraformVersion: '0.12.3'
            - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
              inputs:
                provider: 'aws'
                command: 'init'
                workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(tf.path)'
                commandOptions: '-var "region=$(region)" -var "app_name=$(app.name)" -var "environment=$(environment)"'
                backendServiceAWS: 'tf_nonprod'
                backendAWSBucketName: 'wdrx-deployments'
                backendAWSKey: '$(environment)/$(app.name)/infrastructure/$(region).tfstate'
```

Raw error log:

```
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5973748Z ##[section]Starting: TerraformTaskV2
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5981535Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5981842Z Task         : Terraform
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5982217Z Description  : Execute terraform commands to manage resources on AzureRM, Amazon Web Services(AWS) and Google Cloud Platform(GCP)
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5982555Z Version      : 2.188.1
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5982791Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5983122Z Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://aka.ms/AA5j5pf)
2021-10-29T12:30:16.5983461Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7253372Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.3/x64/terraform init -var region=*** -var app_name=$(app.name) -var environment=test -backend-config=bucket=wdrx-deployments -backend-config=key=test/$(app.name)/infrastructure/***.tfstate -backend-config=region=*** -backend-config=access_key=*** -backend-config=secret_key=***
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7532941Z [0m[1mInitializing modules...[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7558115Z - S3-env in ../Modules/S3
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7578267Z - S3-env.Global-Vars in ../Modules/Global-Vars
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7585434Z - global-vars in 
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7589958Z [31m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7597321Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mUnreadable module directory[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7597847Z 
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7599087Z [0mUnable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat ../Modules/global-vars: no such
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7599550Z file or directory
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7599933Z [0m[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7600324Z [31m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7600779Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mFailed to read module directory[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7600986Z 
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7601405Z [0mModule directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7601808Z [0m[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7602135Z [31m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7602573Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mUnreadable module directory[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7602768Z 
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7603271Z [0mUnable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat ../Modules/global-vars: no such
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7603636Z file or directory
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7603964Z [0m[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7604291Z [31m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7604749Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mFailed to read module directory[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7604936Z 
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7605370Z [0mModule directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7605770Z [0m[0m
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7743995Z ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.3/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
2021-10-29T12:30:16.7756780Z ##[section]Finishing: TerraformTaskV2
```

I have attempted to even move the modules folder inside the tf.path so it is within the same folder as the tf config files and changed the location from "../" to "./". No matter what repo I extract the modules folder to (after downloading as artifact from another build pipeline) it cannot be found when calling it on the tf config files. I am fairly new to DevOps and would appreciate any help or just being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Please format the errors and code again.

Comment: a little hint: if you add `-no-color` to terraform commandline, you'll get rid of all those `[31m` and the log will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define `system.debug: true` variable at global level to enable debug logs - maybe something there will give you a hint:

   ```yaml
   variables:
     system.debug: true
   ```
2. Apart from downloaded artifacts, do you expect to have files checked out from the repo the pipeline is defined in? The `deployment` job doesn't checkout  git files by default, so you may want to add `checkout: self` to steps there.
3. `Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat ../Modules/global-vars` - this is suspicious, I wouldn't expect any symlinks in there. But maybe the error message is just misleading.
4. A useful trick is to [log the whole directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117797/azure-pipelines-is-there-a-way-to-view-the-folder-structure).

   You can do this with a bash script step (might need to `apt install tree` first):

   ```
    - script: tree
   ```

   Or with powershell (will work on MS-hosted linux agent):

   ```
   - pwsh: Get-ChildItem -Path '$(agent.builddirectory)' -recurse
   ```