# Azure Devops Powershell not showing file names for Get-ChildItem

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-core

I'm using the following task in an Azure DevOps pipeline on `vmImage: ubuntu-latest`:

```yml
- pwsh: Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace)
  displayName: 'Show folder contents for debugging'
```

I'm doing so to `dir` out a list of files downloaded in a previous `download` pipeline artifact step. I've also tried regular `powershell` instead of Powershell Core.

The *folder names* are showing up correctly, and *entries* for files are seemingly being shown, but there are no *file names* included at all. Here's a part of the output I do see:

```
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/1f22f03a-d1c6-4983-a08e-39ed349876be.ps1'

    Directory: /home/vsts/work/1

UnixMode   User             Group                 LastWriteTime           Size
--------   ----             -----                 -------------           ----
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096

    Directory: /home/vsts/work/1/s

UnixMode   User             Group                 LastWriteTime           Size
--------   ----             -----                 -------------           ----
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
-rw-r--r-- vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           3507
-rw-r--r-- vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           2370
-rw-r--r-- vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           1636
-rw-r--r-- vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           1056
-rw-r--r-- vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22         913980

et cetera

    Directory: /home/vsts/work/1/s/src

UnixMode   User             Group                 LastWriteTime           Size
--------   ----             -----                 -------------           ----
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096
drwxr-xr-x vsts             docker             04/03/2022 16:22           4096

et cetera
```

Why is it not showing file names? How can I ensure that it does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74316936/2050637

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the effective console width is `80` characters (as reflected in `[Console]::WindowWidth`, in which case the `Name` column doesn't fit and is simply dropped.

Ideally, Azure would allow you to specify a larger console-window width (I don't know if that is an option - do tell us if you know),<sup>[1]</sup> but a *workaround* is to pipe to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) and use its `-Width` parameter; e.g.:

```sh
- pwsh: Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace) | Out-String -Width 160
  displayName: 'Show folder contents for debugging'
```

Note:

- As the cmdlet's name suggests, it converts `Get-ChildItem`'s output objects to *strings*, so this is only suitable for capturing *for-display* representations.
- As you note, if you don't need *all* columns, a simpler solution - which additionally avoids stringification - is to pipe to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object); e.g.:

```sh
- pwsh: Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace) | Select-Object UnixMode, Length, Name
  displayName: 'Show folder contents for debugging'
```

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, *setting* the dimensions of the `[Console]` class - e.g. `[Console]::WindowWidth = 160` is *not* supported on Unix-like platforms.</sup>

Comment: I tried [this solution](https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/articles/powershell-server-changing-terminal-width.rst) to change `BufferSize` on the `Get-Host` but Azure reports "_setting BufferSize: Operation is not supported on this platform._".

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Jeroen. Good point re `Select-Object` offering a simpler solution, if not all columns are needed - I've updated the answer accordingly. Yes, _setting_ the dimensions of the `[Console]` (which is what it comes down to) is unfortunately not supported on Unix-like platforms.